# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} || \textbf{1}_{A_n}f||_p = ||f||_\infty $

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ is $\sigma-$finite and write $X = \cup_n A_n$ where $(A_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of elements in $A_n \in \mathcal{E}$. Then for every $f \in \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$ I have to show that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} || \textbf{1}_{A_n}f||_p = ||f||_\infty $$

A well-known result is that $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}||f||_p = ||f||_\infty$ which I have to use but I am not sure other than that where to begin.

I know that if $p \in [1, \infty)$ then $||f||_p = \left( \int_X |f|^p d \mu \right)^{1/p}$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My first thought: If $\mu(A_n) < \infty$, then $\lim_{p \to \infty}\lVert 1_{A_n}f \rVert_p = \lVert 1_{A_n}f \rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: There is a general dominated convergence theorem that might help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for the well-known result you reference, you do require more assumptions (like $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ or that $f$ is in $L^r(A_n)$ for some $r$).

However, assuming this result,
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty}\| \mathbb{1}_{A_n}f\|_p=\| \mathbb{1}_{A_n}f\|_\infty,
$$

the question reduces to showing
$$
\lim_{n}\|f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty=\| f\|_\infty.
$$
This follows from the fact that $\| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty$ is increasing, and $\sup_{n}\| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty$. To see the second of these, fix $\epsilon>0$ and find $B_\epsilon\subset X$ with $|f|>\|f\|_\infty-\epsilon$ on $B_\epsilon$ and $\mu(B_\epsilon)>0$. By continuity of measure, there is an $n$ large enough so that $\mu(A_n\cap B_\epsilon)>0$, and
$$
\| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty\geq \| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n\cap B_\epsilon}\|_\infty>\|f\|_\infty-\epsilon.
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary and $\| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty\leq \| f\|_\infty$, $\sup_{n}\| f\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\|_\infty=\| f\|_\infty$.